# Center my ul elements on the page without losing the bullet points

Tags: html, css

I am trying the center my ul elements on one line, in the center of the page without losing the bullet points.

[image]

I want those two ul elements to be placed in the middle of the page. I tried various CSS methods but I am still not managing to make it work.

```css
.list li {
    float: left;
    list-style-position: inside;
    list-style-type: disc;
    margin-right: 1em;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
    <li><a href="X site" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Sitemap</a></li>
    <li>© <?php echo date('Y'); ?> | All rights reserved</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix it using the :before selector

```css
.list{ text-align: center; }
.list li
    {
        display: inline;
        margin-right: 1em;
    }
    .list li:before {
        content: '\2022';
        margin-right: 0.5em;
        color: red;
    }
```

```html
 <ul class="list">
  <li><a href="X site" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Sitemap</a></li>
  <li>© <?php echo date('Y'); ?> | All rights reserved</li>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

To center elements with css, should be provided some width, in this case 100%.

```
ul {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

If this won't work, probably there's another wrapper div avoiding this property, and you should post your whole code here.

Provide to us a [MCVE example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), welcome to stackOverflow!

Comment: Ok, did you inserted text-align: center too?

Comment: I did but to no avail

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `width` of the `ul` container (otherwise it has no width because all of it's child elements are floated elements).

Once the container has width you can use `margin: 0 auto;` to center it:

```css
.list {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 330px;
}
.list li
{
    float: left;
    list-style-position: inside;
    list-style-type: disc;
    margin-right: 1em;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
    <li><a href="X site" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Sitemap</a></li>
    <li>2018 | All rights reserved</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It works correctly when i increase the width size to 600px for example, but its still not properly centered to the page. When i tried to do width: 100% , it moves the elements back to the left

Comment: Why would you need to increase the size to 600px? The width of the content is not 600px... you should put there the exact width of the container.

Comment: When i put the 330 px, it centers but the second bullet goes to the line below.

Comment: So try 340/350/360 - depends on the font/size you use in your css. You should put the minimum value, not the maximum.

Comment: So i should try to do some trial and error until I find the smallest width size in px for the container ? Keep incrementing by 1px until its correctly centered ?

Comment: The best solution is to use the developer toolbar to see that "live" while you change the width value there.

Comment: The size of 350px works correctly. Now when I display my page in mobile view, how can I be able to place li elements in a new line if it dosent fit its current line

Comment: Well, this is a complete different question :) You should search for css media query

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
.list {
     position: relative;
     float: left;
     left: 50%;
     margin: 0 auto;
     padding: 0;
}



li {
    position: relative;
     float: left;
     right: 50%;
     margin-right: 10px;
     padding: 5px 10px;
     background: #fff;
     list-style: disc;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `::before`

```css
ul {
  text-align: center;
}

.list li
{
  display: inline;
}

.list li::before {
  content: '•';
  margin: 0px 0.3rem;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
    <li><a href="X site" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Sitemap</a></li>
    <li>© <?php echo date('Y'); ?> | All rights reserved</li>
</ul>
```